# MPMoviePlayerViewController / MPMoviePlayerController will not play the same movie twice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

Steps to replicate: 
1. Call playMovieAtURL.  Use this url: (http://nov8rixstorage.blob.core.windows.net/searchpad/tutorial_portrait.mov)
2. Let the movie start then press Done.
3. Call playMovieAtURL again using the same URL.

Result: MPMoviePlayerViewController animates in; flashes a few times; and closes with error in notification object. ("Server is not correctly configured.")

This is very strange.  Making things stranger; the movie player will not play anything again until the app is deleted from the device (simulator or iphone).  Upon re-deployment it will play the movie perfectly once again; but alas on the second play it will repeat the above behavior.

What am I doing wrong?  Can anyone reproduce this?

```
- (void) playMovieAtURL: (NSURL*) theURL {
    [theURL retain];

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:theURL];

    if (mp)
    {
        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector: @selector(playbackDidFinish:) 
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                                   object:mp.moviePlayer];

        [mp release];
    }

    [theURL release];
}

-(void) playbackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:player];
    [player stop];
    [self dismissMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated];
}
```

Edit: Can anyone replicate this? Anyone?

Comment: Still haven't figured this one out.  Is this a bug with the SDK or am I missing something?  Seems strange that the movie will play once but is unable to play a second time.

Comment: @jeeva your link is spammy and annoying.

Answer (score 0):

try moviePlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of:

```
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
```

You should write:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [aNotification object];
```